# App contains non-public API usage, please review errors

Tags: ios, iphone, submit, itunes-store

I am trying to upload my iOS app on app store but i am getting an error when i try to upload binary. My app is already available on iTunes but this time i am getting this error and don't know how to fix it. Error snapshot is attached below

[image]

Comment: Do you have a method in your app that is `_terminateWithStatus:`?  If so, the easiest solution would be to rename that method.

Comment: I don't think it's as easy as renaming the method. It states the he's using a non-public API, not that there's some type of namespace conflict or anything. Quick search revealed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031356/finding-private-api-call-terminatewithstatus

Comment: I don't know about otool where i should run these commands?