# FaceBook SDK - The app references non-public selectors in payload "setDescription"

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, payload

Im using the last FaceBook SDK + `DEFacebookComposeView`
I already cheked the `user.id` commun issue and changed into `[user objectForKey:@"id"];`
this one is about "`setDescription`" the issue is I belive the "description"

Wich file should I change ? from FaceBook SDK ?

When I execute the app from terminal to have a more precise error report.
using this way :
[Finding Private API Call _terminateWithStatus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031356/finding-private-api-call-terminatewithstatus)
when I execute I get nothing

To be extrem, I deleted ALL but the facebook SDK, ALL other frameworks, all other scripts
My Xcode project just have 
1 file.m 
1 file.h 
The last FaceBook SDK
So I'm sure this not coming from my script or other Frameworks variable/function conflict, but :
the warning remain...

Thank you so much for your help !
D.