# Finding which framework makes the Private API Call _terminateWithStatus

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-privateapi

I have just received an email from Apple stating my iOS app has been rejected for the call of _terminateWithStatus. Unfortunately I have no idea which framework might be the one making this call.

I could find "terminateWithStatus" with the follow "strings" command executed on the compiled executable, so I know that it is there, but no idea how to figure out which framework makes that call.

```
strings myapp | grep 'terminateWithStatus'
```

I do not have GHUnit framework, which was the culprit for the others seeing the same issue few years back - see [Finding Private API Call _terminateWithStatus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031356/finding-private-api-call-terminatewithstatus)

This is what otool shows:

```
$ otool -L myapp
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 307.5.0)
    /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 254.6.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.8)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 30.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 492.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 754.2.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1349.55.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics (compatibility version 64.0.0, current version 1070.22.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2101.0.62)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2101.0.62)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo (compatibility version 1.2.0, current version 1.5.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/GLKit.framework/GLKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 87.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 775.2.37)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 888.50.20)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 603.1.30)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/SafariServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 603.1.30)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 3600.7.47)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore (compatibility version 1.2.0, current version 1.11.0)
    /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.5)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1349.54.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.50.2)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 811.4.18)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
```

Anybody has any idea how to figure out which framework might be the one making that call?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am going to answer my own question.
It turns out, the GoogleToolboxForMax framework which has this _terminateWithStatus call, which I installed via cocoapods/

I figured it out by running

```
$ grep -rn "terminateWithStatus" *
Pods/GoogleToolboxForMac/UnitTesting/GTMIPhoneUnitTestDelegate.m:34:- (void)_terminateWithStatus:(int)status;
Pods/GoogleToolboxForMac/UnitTesting/GTMIPhoneUnitTestDelegate.m:115:      = [UIApplication instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(_terminateWithStatus:)];
Pods/GoogleToolboxForMac/UnitTesting/GTMIPhoneUnitTestDelegate.m:120:      [terminateInvocation setSelector:@selector(_terminateWithStatus:)];
```

Here I have modified the method and all references `_terminateWithStatus` to `_terminateWithStatusModified` and then I could submit my app.