# How to submit the IAP's display name in iTunes Connect for review?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I updated the IAP's display name, it show "yellow" status now, but how can I submit it for review? or it is already "waiting for review" now? I don't want to update my app, only want to update the IAP's display name.

Comment: After Dec 2017, apple restricted that you need the get your plans verified too along with your app. Upon changing the name, are you receiving `Ready to Submit` with yellow dot? or `Missing metadata`?

Comment: Can you add some pictures in your post to explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: Can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031356/finding-private-api-call-terminatewithstatus